# Calculating Average Of 30 Random Numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to make a console application that generates 30 random numbers and then calculates the average of those numbers....  I'm really finding it difficult to calculate the average.... Any help/guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class AV{
    public static void Main(){
        int[] averageGrade= new int[31];//Array to store    students
        int cntr;
        System.Random rnd=new System.Random();
        for(cntr=0;cntr<31;cntr++){
            averageGrade[cntr]=rnd.Next(0,101);
            Console.Write("Student {0}, Grade:    {1}",cntr,averageGrade[cntr]);
            Console.WriteLine(getLevel(averageGrade[cntr]));
        }
    }// End of main method

    private static string getLevel(int averageGrade) {

        double average = averageGrade.Average (t =>  t);    
        //calculate average here

    }// end of getLevel
}// end of AV class
```

Comment: But you didn't mentioned what problem are you facing with your current implementation?

Comment: Did you try asking your professor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problems were that you have: first - accept an array parameter in your `getLevel` method which I renamed to `GetAverage`. Second - you should move `Console.Write("Student {0}, Grade:    {1}", cntr, averageGrades[cntr]);` outside of `for` loop. And something small: your array is currently of 31 elements.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class AV
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] averageGrades = new int[30];//Array to store    students
        int cntr;
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        for (cntr = 0; cntr < averageGrades.Length; cntr++)
        {
            averageGrades[cntr] = rnd.Next(0, 101);
            Console.Write("Student {0}, Grade:    {1}", cntr, averageGrades[cntr]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(GetAverage(averageGrades));
    }

    private static double GetAverage(int[] averageGrade)
    {
        return averageGrade.Average(t => t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an array to your method

```
private static string getLevel(int[] averageGrade)  

getLevel(averageGrade)
```

The average of a single number *is* that same number, the method you're using is designed to work on an `IEnumerable`, I.e your original array.

Since you're now passing in an array you don't need this to be called from within your for loop either so you can move it outside after the for loop.

Comment: Note: Don't forget to return something from this method, I'd recommend returning the actual average instead of a string, but whatever works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
    double[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 0 };
    double average1 = array1.Average();
    Console.WriteLine(average1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do, but probably the idea of your assignment is to do it yourself instead using existing libraries...

```
    public double GetAverage()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 30) // Create an array of 30 items
            .Select(s => rnd.Next(0, 101)) // Select a random number for each item
            .Average(); // Get the average 
    }
```